# Windows Store App style resources don't seem to be working

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, app.xaml

I have a style resources that looks like this: 
**Edit: Added code styling**

```
<Style x:Key="PageHeaderTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,30,40"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

This is the standard style that is added when you start the app, but for some reason all my page headers use Black as the foreground color instead of white.

**Edit: Here is an example of how I am applying the style**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Group.Title}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" />
```

In App.xaml I have the RequestedTheme set to "Dark".

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How do you apply that style to your `TextBlock`s?

Comment: Hi Filip, I edited the post adding an example of how we use it. It's the standard code produced by Visual Studio when you add the page.

Comment: So your font gets rendered as black on black background - making it invisible?

Comment: Absolutely. Why does it seem obvious why it's happening :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything obvious. I think you'd need to share a small repro project